# How to show a confidence interval in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I need to show a confidence interval, like in this image:

[image]
but I don't know how to do it. I've tried doing `lb.fill_between(x, (y1-ci), (y1+ci), color = 'b', alpha = 0.1)` but it returns the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fill_between'`.
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [10, 100, 1000]
y1 = [215103, 22824279.7, 22063128311]
y2 = [211298.5, 21315505.2, 20563930722]

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)

ci = 1300
#la = plt.plot(x,y,'b*', label = 'normal')
lb = plt.plot(x,y1, '#FA8072', label = 'LI')
lc = plt.plot(x,y2, '#7FFFD4', label = 'LU')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.title("L1-dcache-loads")
plt.xscale("log")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `lb` is a list. You need to `plt.fill_between`. Note that `y1-ci` will also give you an error

Comment: @DavidG when i do `plt.fill_between` I get this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`, just like you said. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fill_between` like this:

```
plt.figure()
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, edgecolor='g', facecolor='g', alpha=0.3)
```

`y1` is your lower bound curve, and `y2` is your upper bound curve. Output:

[image: bounds]

In your example:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y1, '#FA8072', label = 'LI')
plt.fill_between(x, np.array(y1)-ci, np.array(y1)+ci, edgecolor='r', facecolor='r', alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(x,y2, '#7FFFD4', label = 'LU')
plt.fill_between(x, np.array(y2)-ci, np.array(y2)+ci, edgecolor='g', facecolor='g', alpha=0.3)
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.title("L1-dcache-loads")
plt.xscale("log")
```

But the intervals are too small to see.

[image: updated]